# Why isn't the output of the LT1168 equal to its input in this very basic circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, instrumentation-amplifier

Consider the following circuit (made in LTSpice IV):

[image]

And it's simulation:

[image]

This is unexpected to me. I thought the output would be equal the input, since I didn't include a gain resistor on purpose:

$$R_{\text{gain}} = \infty$$
$$A_V = \left(V_+ - V_-\right)\left(1 + \dfrac{2R}{R_{\text{gain}}}\right) = \left(V_+ - V_-\right)\left(1 + \dfrac{2R}{\infty}\right) = V_+ - V_- \qquad \text{?}$$

What am I missing here? Is this an issue with LTSpice? If I construct this circuit, can I expect it to have the output equal to the input?

Comment: You forgot to connect the reference pin (presumably to ground).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to connect the reference pin of the in amp. This is usually connected to ground. Here's the block diagram of the in amp, taken from [its datasheet](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1168fa.pdf):

[image]

With the reference pin open the difference amplifier (composed of \$R_5\$ through \$R_8\$ and the op amp \$A_3\$) does not have the normal gain of 1.

Add a ground connection to the reference pin (the one near the "LT1168" in your image) and you'll get a gain of 1.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the deep explanation. In fact, looking at the diagram, it is possible to see that the equation becomes **2Vplus - Vminus** instead of **Vplus - Vminus** if the REF pin is open, which perfectly explains the result of my simulation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A single ended input that you have , has a gain of 0.5.

that is why.

Use a differential source or use single ended gain.